# TikZ picture too tall

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am typesetting the following equation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f\left(
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt];
\path (0:0cm) node (center) {};
\path (0:1cm) node (v1) {};
\path (72:1cm) node (v2) {};
\path (2*72:1cm) node (v3) {};
\path (3*72:1cm) node (v4) {};
\path (4*72:1cm) node (v5) {};
\draw (center) -- (v1)
(center) -- (v2)
(center) -- (v3)
(center) -- (v4)
(center) -- (v5)
(v1) -- (v2)
(v2) -- (v3)
(v3) -- (v4)
(v4) -- (v5)
(v5) -- (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\right)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

However, the brackets become almost twice the size of what is needed. Is there any way of removing the white space below the graph?

Comment: Instead of `\path (0:0cm) node (center) {};` you can also write `\node at (0:0cm) (center) {};`. It's a little shorter. Also have a look on the `edge` operator which can be used to draw connections between nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `tikzpicture`s are placed with the lower border onto the bounding box, like images. Therefore it has a large height but zero depth. You can set the baseline of the picture using the `baseline` option. On its own it set the baseline through the origin `(0,0)`, but you can also provide any other TikZ coordinate. This coordinate is evaluated at the end of the picture. If you use the special node `current bounding box` the center of the image is used independently where the original lies. I personally would add an offset so that the center of the picture is around the half height of the *f*:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f\left(
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box)}]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt];
\path (0:0cm) node (center) {};
\path (0:1cm) node (v1) {};
\path (72:1cm) node (v2) {};
\path (2*72:1cm) node (v3) {};
\path (3*72:1cm) node (v4) {};
\path (4*72:1cm) node (v5) {};
\draw (center) -- (v1)
(center) -- (v2)
(center) -- (v3)
(center) -- (v4)
(center) -- (v5)
(v1) -- (v2)
(v2) -- (v3)
(v3) -- (v4)
(v4) -- (v5)
(v5) -- (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\right)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Before:                              After:

[image: Before]
[image: After]